# String Indices must be integers, not str - API

Tags: python, string, api

I have an interesting behavior happening with my program.

i have the following methods:

```
def getMarket(self, Currency):
    return self.public_api('GetMarket/' + Currency + '_BTC')

def getBalance(self, Currency):
    self.api_params.clear()
    self.api_params['Currency'] = Currency
    return self.private_api('GetBalance')
```

---

```
my_api = buyBot(API_KEY, API_SECRET)


pumpCoin = my_api.getMarket('OSC')
pumpRawRate = pumpCoin['Data']['High']
pumpRawQty = .02
pumpBuyRate = my_api.calculateBuy(pumpRawRate)
pumpQty = float(pumpRawQty)/float(pumpBuyRate)
pumpSellRate = pumpCoin['Data']['Low']

pumpSellCoin = my_api.getBalance('OSC')


pumpSellAmount = pumpSellCoin["Data"]["Total"]

print str(pumpRawRate) + '\n' + str(pumpBuyRate) + '\n' + str(pumpSellRate) + '\n' + str(pumpQty) + '\n' + str(pumpSellAmount)`
```

From section: `pumpCoin = my_api.getMarket('OSC')` to `pumpSellRate = pumpCoin['Data']['Low']`, i have no problems getting the information and working with it.

Problem seems to be starting with line: `pumpSellCoin = my_api.getBalance('OSC')`

I get the following Error message:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\XXXXXX.py", line 92, in <module>
    pumpSellAmount = pumpSellCoin["Data"]["Total"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

if i run: `print (my_api.getBalance('OSC')`, i am able to see all the private API information that is retrieved by that call, however i am not sure why it is giving me a problem when i try to call 1 specific item in the stack.

Let me know if you need any more information on this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have looked at the other posts and so far i can't seem to figure out the exact cause.

This is the private_api code

```
def private_api(self, meth):
    time.sleep(1)
    params = self.api_params
    url = self.apisite + meth
    nonce = str(int(time.time()))
    post_data = json.dumps(params)
    hash = hashlib.md5()
    hash.update(post_data)
    base64hash = base64.b64encode(hash.digest())
    sig = self.apikey + "POST" + urllib.quote_plus(url).lower() + nonce + base64hash
    hmacsig = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(self.apisecret), sig, hashlib.sha256).digest())
    hdr = "amx " + self.apikey + ":" + hmacsig + ":" + nonce
    headers = { 'Authorization': hdr, 'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data=post_data, headers=headers)
    return urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Comment: What is `my_api.getBalance('OSC')`, and what is its type and structure?

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite.  Or just inspect/print `pumpSellCoin` prior to the offending line.  Is it what you expect it to be? The Traceback seems to imply that it is a string.

Comment: The implementation of `self.private_api` is critical here, and you haven't provided it. We can't help you without a [MCVE].

Comment: This is the stack
{
    "Success":true,
    "Error":null,
    "Data":[
            {
                "CurrencyId":1,
                "Symbol":"BTC",
                "Total":"10300",
                "Available":"6700.00000000",
                "Unconfirmed":"2.00000000",
                "HeldForTrades":"3400,00000000",
                "PendingWithdraw":"200.00000000",
                "Address":"Address",
  "BaseAddress": "Address",
                "Status":"OK",
                "StatusMessage":""
            },
            {
                ...
            }
           ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this to your code:

```
print('pumpSellCoin', type(pumpSellCoin["Data"]), type(pumpSellCoin["Data"]["Total"]))
pumpSellAmount = pumpSellCoin["Data"]["Total"]
```

This will show you that one of your variables is a list or a string and not a dictionary and you need to access is using a number and not a name like `"Data"` or `"Total"`

Try this example:

```
test = 'abcde'
print(type(test))
print(test[0])
print(test[2:4])
print(test['whatever']) # this results in TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Hi Joe.  I changed the variable to: pumpSellBal since that is what i am using, but i received the same error message.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\XXXXX.py", line 92, in <module>
    print('pumpSellBal', type(pumpSellBal["Data"]), type(pumpSellBal["Data"]["Total"]))
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Please check the type of all variables and see if you are at some point applying a `['whatever']` to a string. This is what your error message indicates.

Comment: i got the following modified to my code:


'{"Success":true,"Error":null,"Data":[{"CurrencyId":44,"Symbol":"OK","Total":0.00000000,"Available":0.00000000,"Unconfirmed":0.00000000,"HeldForTrades":0.00000000,"PendingWithdraw":0.00000000,"Address":null,"Status":"OK","StatusMessage":null,"BaseAddress":null}]}


<type 'str'>
{
Su

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\XXX.py", line 110, in <module>
    print(pumpSellBal['Data'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str'

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I used your Test Code above to check what the difference between the pumpCoin = my_api.getMarket(coinP) & pumpSellBal = my_api.getBalance(coinP) is and found the first one is a dictionary which is why it works with my code, and the second is a string.

I'll need to figure out how to call on the value i need from here.

Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0):

if i run the program as follows:

```
    my_api = buyBot(API_KEY, API_SECRET)


pumpCoin = my_api.getMarket('OSC')
pumpRawRate = pumpCoin['Data']['High']
pumpRawQty = .02
pumpBuyRate = my_api.calculateBuy(pumpRawRate)
pumpQty = float(pumpRawQty)/float(pumpBuyRate)
pumpSellRate = pumpCoin['Data']['Low']

pumpSellBal = my_api.getBalance('OSC')

print pumpSellBal


#print('pumpSellBal', type(pumpSellBal["Data"]), type(pumpSellBal["Data"]["Total"]))


#pumpSellAmount = pumpSellBal['Data']['Total']

print str(pumpRawRate) + '\n' + str(pumpBuyRate) + '\n' + str(pumpSellRate) + '\n' + str(pumpQty) #+ '\n' + str(pumpSellAmount)
```

i get the following results:

```
{"Success":true,"Error":null,"Data":[{"CurrencyId":235,"Symbol":"OSC","Total":8561.03652012,"Available":0.00000000,"Unconfirmed":0.00000000,"HeldForTrades":8561.03652012,"PendingWithdraw":0.00000000,"Address":null,"Status":"OK","StatusMessage":null,"BaseAddress":null}]}
1.61e-06
2.415e-06
1.25e-06
8281.57349896
```

So i am definitely able to communicate back and forward, however the issue only seems to be when i try to work with a single piece of information from pumpSellBal = my_api.getBalance('OSC')